# How do I open Dolphin in a certain folder from the terminal?

Tags: kde, taskbar, dolphin

I would like to add a starter icon to my task bar that runs `dolphin` but initially starts in a folder I would like to specify

the [Dolphin Handbook](http://docs.kde.org/stable/de/applications/dolphin/index.html) doesn't explain this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this in the terminal: `dolphin /usr/home/` (choose your own path). For more information, read the man page (also available online: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/dolphin.1.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to open dolphin from your current path in your terminal just use,

```
dolphin . &
```

Answer (score 4):

**Help pages**

The KDE applications have the help - with the Dolphin:

```
:~$ dolphin --help
Usage: dolphin [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] [Url] 

File Manager

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --select                  The files and directories passed as arguments will be selected.
  --split                   Dolphin will get started with a split view.

Arguments:
  Url                       Document to open
```

**Launch with the default application**

The KDE has the "Default Appications" in the KDE system settings.

The kfmclient is:

```
:~$ kfmclient --help
Usage: kfmclient [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [KDE-tempfile-options] [options] command [URL(s)] 

KDE tool for opening URLs from the command line

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-kde-tempfile       Show KDE-tempfile specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --noninteractive          Non interactive use: no message boxes
  --commands                Show available commands

Arguments:
  command                   Command (see --commands)
  URL(s)                    Arguments for command
```

Opening the directory with the default file manager:

```
kfmclient exec /path/to/the/directory/
```

Comment: This would integrate well with a bash profile alias or function

Answer (score 0):

Use **--select** option, for example

`dolphin --select .`

`dolphin --select /`

`dolphin --select /path/you/want/.`

It won't run as a foreground job in the terminal, so it won't block
your terminal session and there is no for & etc and it can take extra
arguments